# How do I filter the data based on search input from array of objects in React, ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the JSON data pattern coming from API in the below way. I was able to filter the data with `body` key. I'm trying to implement the search functionality which should search all the array of objects irrespective of `key` based on user input. Could someone please guide how to achieve this. I tried using nested for loop to get the individual key but not luck.

```
[
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnccusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore is et"
  }
  ...
]
```

Key based search logic that I'm currently using

```
const filteredData = data.filter(item =>
      item.body.includes(searchTerm.value)
    );
    this.setState({ filteredData: filteredData });
```

I created a working example using [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-6ynn5). Could anyone please guide how to achieve the Search results from entire array of Objects?

Comment: It's better to have a dropdown alongside, let user the key by which they want to search and then search for that key for the particular value

Comment: Ah I see. But, is there a way I can search the entire table ( array of objects ) irrespective of the key based on user entered input string? @CodeManiac

Comment: Yes you can, you need to search loop though all the entries and use `some` method if any of the value matches then you can return that element,

Comment: Try `const filteredData = data.filter(item => Object.values(item).some(val => val.toString().includes(searchTerm.value)))`

Comment: OMG! That was it man. Appreciate it! @David Can you post it as a answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Sure thing @Pavan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const filteredData = data.filter(item => Object.values(item).some(val => val.toString().includes(searchTerm.value)));
```